# Characteristic polynomials of 2 x 2 matrices with entries in a finite field

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A \subset \mathbb{F}_{q}$ be a set of size $n$ (no particular condition on $n$ and $q$ unless you really need it). Given a random monic polynomial $P(x) \in \mathbb{F}_{q}[x]$ of degree $2$, how many $2 \times 2$ matrices with entries in $A$ have characteristic polynomial $P$? Can one write an estimate in terms of $|A|$ and $q$?

(You can assume that $q$ is prime if it helps)

Or a non-random version: given some monic polynomial $P(x) \in \mathbb{F}_{q}[x]$ of degree $2$, how many $2 \times 2$ matrices with entries in $A$ can have characteristic polynomial $P(x)$? (lower/upper bounds)

Comment: It is at least obvious that the precise number does not only depend on $A$ and $q$. If you take $A=\{1\}$, the answer is one for $P=x^2-2x$ and zero for all all other choices of $P$.

Comment: While I think this is a very interesting problem, but finding a solution will not be easy. This will depend on all of $P$, $q$, $A$.

Comment: One may start working on relatively easy cases such as $P(x) = (x-a)(x-b)$.